# populate a select dropdown on the basis of other other select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I populate a select dropdown whose values are dependent on what is selected in the parent dropdown. E-g, First dropdown has country names in it, and on selection the next dropdown would load the corresponding states of that country, selected in first dropdown. And then say I have a third dropdown, where I am putting the image of that particular state, that corresponds to what is selected in second dropdown.

How can this be done in JQuery.

E-g

Country>>>>> States>>>>>>Map of This State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this plugin: [cascade](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cascade)
You can have a few css classes for each state those flag you want to show with appropriate background image and swith class on second dropdown change event:

```
var statesList = [
    {
    'When': 'US',
    'Value': 'nope',
    'Text': 'Select state'},
{
    'When': 'US',
    'Value': 'US_AL',
    'Text': 'Alabama'},

{
    'When': 'US',
    'Value': 'US_AK',
    'Text': 'Alaska'},
{
    'When': 'IN',
    'Value': 'nope',
    'Text': 'Select state'},
{
    'When': 'IN',
    'Value': 'IN_AP',
    'Text': 'Andra Pradesh'},

{
    'When': 'IN',
    'Value': 'IN_AS',
    'Text': 'Assam'}
];

$("#state").cascade("#country", {
    list: statesList,
    template: function(item) {
        return "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>";
    },
    match: function(selectedValue) {
        return this.When == selectedValue;
    }
});

$("#state").change(function() {
    $("#flag").removeClass().addClass($(this).val());
});

<label>Country
    <select id="country">
        <option value="nope">Choose a country</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="IN">India</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label>State
    <select id="state">
        <option value='nope'>Select a country before</option>
    </select>
</label>

<span id="flag" style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 1px;">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin to do this

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryselectcombo/

Or you can see the answer of

[How can I populate another dropdown with the onChange event of the first dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293959/how-can-i-populate-another-dropdown-with-the-onchange-event-of-the-first-dropdow)

Comment: Is it not possible without a plugin

Comment: possible but its less elegant solution.Please take a clear look at the answer of question link i had given with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first dropdown "onChange" event you should call an ajax function which will return the second dropdown items array (... or something). And when the ajax call is completed you just need to append the result items.

Pseudo:

```
$select1.change(function(){
  caountry_id = select1.find(':selected').val();
  $.get( // ajax call
    'path/to/script',  // php script, this will return the states
    {country: country_id},
    function(data){  // callback function
       $.each(data, function(key, value){   // iterate trough the items
           $select2.       // append nem options
              append($("<option></option>").
              attr("value",key).
              text(value));
       });
    },
    'json'
});
```

Have fun! :)

(Sorry for my english :"> )